# Returns only one data AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Here's what i'm doing. Im trying to return a `data` through my database and i want the `data` to display in an organized manner. I need to distribute the data in different `html tables` based on what `year` or `semester` the data is. If you know about curriculum it's like that.

here's my algorithm. first i initialize a `variable` outside the `while loop` which is **`$a`**, if `semester` = `1st` and `year` = `1` then it will go through another if which is checking if **`$a`** = 1 if it's equals it will create a `div` that contains part of the `html tables` then it will print out the `data` fetched from the database in `td` after that it will check again if **`$a`** = 1 then it will create the last part of the `html tables`.

To summarize. I want to distribute the data based on what semester and year the data is. But the problem is only one data is shown i have two data which equals to `1st semester and year 1`.

Data
[image]

```
    $a = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($row['semester'] == '1st' && $row['year'] == 1){

           /*This if condition below is set to initiliaze the table headers only once*/

            if($a == 1){
                $output .='<div class="table-responsive">
                           <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th class="text-center">Subject Code</th>
                                  <th class="text-center">Subject Title</th>
                                  <th class="text-center">Units</th>
                                  <th class="text-center">Pre-req</th>
                                  <th class="text-center">Co-req</th>
                              </tr>
                          </thead>
                      <tbody>';
              }

                $output .= '<tr>
                         <td class="text-center">'.$row['code'].'</td>
                         <td class="text-center">'.$row['title'].'</td>
                         <td class="text-center">'.$row['unit'].'</td>
                         <td class="text-center">'.$row['prereq'].'</td>
                         <td class="text-center">'.$row['corequisite'].'</td>
                      </tr>';


   /*This if condition below is set to initiliaze the table headers only once*/

              if($a == 1){
                $output .= '</tbody>
                            </table>
                          </div';
                $a = 2;
              }

        }

    }
   echo $output;
```

Comment: the second data-row is outside the table, because you close it at the end of the first row.

Comment: why don't you simply put table head _before_ the loop and table closing _after_ the while-loop?

Comment: Please do not use integer for boolean condition. Set $a to false at the beggining of you code. Then do if($a){$a = true}

Comment: Better yet, return JSON and build the HTML on the client. That way the data logic and UI logic are kept completely separate

Comment: @Jeff because it is not only one table it is 10 table to exact.

Comment: still, you close the table before you insert the second row.

Comment: @Jeff no it will not close that's why i initialize a variable outside the loop and put an if condition there so it will not close. it will only execute once.

Comment: yes. it will only execute once. _in the first run_. But you want it in the _last_ run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that you close the table already in your first run loop, but it only should be closed at the end of the loop, and only if you opened the table at all.
It's easier to get the logic right if you use boolean variables and give them names that mean something.

```
$hasFoundAtLeastOneRow = false;
$firstRow = true;
$output = ''; // if you haven't above, you need to initialize that string before you can do a '.='
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row['semester'] == '1st' && $row['year'] == 1){

       /*This if condition below is set to initiliaze the table headers only once*/

          if($firstRow){
              $output .='<div class="table-responsive">
                       <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th class="text-center">Subject Code</th>
                              <th class="text-center">Subject Title</th>
                              <th class="text-center">Units</th>
                              <th class="text-center">Pre-req</th>
                              <th class="text-center">Co-req</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                  <tbody>';
          }

          $output .= '<tr>
                    <td class="text-center">'.$row['code'].'</td>
                    <td class="text-center">'.$row['title'].'</td>
                    <td class="text-center">'.$row['unit'].'</td>
                    <td class="text-center">'.$row['prereq'].'</td>
                    <td class="text-center">'.$row['corequisite'].'</td>
                 </tr>';
        $hasFoundAtLeastOneRow = true;   // we have at least one entry in our table
        $firstRow = false;  // set this to false, since we just worked the first row
    }

}

if($hasFoundAtLeastOneRow) {
    $output .= '</tbody>
              </table>
            </div';
} else {
    // optional
    $output = "nothing found";
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: just one more question sir, i will create more tables in that loop how can i do that?

Comment: Because other than that table i have a table for 1st year 1st sem 2nd year 1st sem and so on.

Answer (score 0):

the reason you get only one result is because you didn't increment the value of a `$a = 1;` instead of using `$a=2;` increment it because it skips a result and also place ending tag outside the loop

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($row['semester'] == '1st' && $row['year'] == 1){

           /*This if condition below is set to initiliaze the table headers only once*/

            if($a == 1){
                $output .='<div class="table-responsive">
                           <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th class="text-center">Subject Code</th>
                                  <th class="text-center">Subject Title</th>
                                  <th class="text-center">Units</th>
                                  <th class="text-center">Pre-req</th>
                                  <th class="text-center">Co-req</th>
                              </tr>
                          </thead>
                      <tbody>';
              }

                $output .= '<tr>
                         <td class="text-center">'.$row['code'].'</td>
                         <td class="text-center">'.$row['title'].'</td>
                         <td class="text-center">'.$row['unit'].'</td>
                         <td class="text-center">'.$row['prereq'].'</td>
                         <td class="text-center">'.$row['corequisite'].'</td>
                      </tr>';


   /*This if condition below is set to initiliaze the table headers only once*/



        }
      $a++;
    }
  $output .= '</tbody></table></div';

   echo $output;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th class="text-center">Subject Code</th>
              <th class="text-center">Subject Title</th>
              <th class="text-center">Units</th>
              <th class="text-center">Pre-req</th>
              <th class="text-center">Co-req</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php   
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($row['semester'] == '1st' && $row['year'] == 1)
        {
?>      
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center"><?=$row['code']?></td>
                <td class="text-center"><?=$row['title']?></td>
                <td class="text-center"><?=$row['unit']?></td>
                <td class="text-center"><?=$row['prereq']?></td>
                <td class="text-center"><?=$row['corequisite']?></td>
            </tr>
<?php
        }
    }
?>  
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Explanations are the main reason why people come to StackOverflow. Please edit.